# Reading a cell text as a Formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, spreadsheet, google-query-language

I want excel (and google spreadsheets) to read a text as a formula.

Cell A1: 1+2

Cell A2: =readAsFormula(A1)

So cell A2 should show 3.

Can`t find any way to do it, and I wanted to avoid making a custom function for it.

Any ideas?

Comment: left() and right() then use an if() to recognize and drive a calculation. But a UDF is much easier, think I have a q+a doing that on here.

Comment: @SolaMike can you elaborate more? Could not understand how you would apply that.

Comment: If you want Excel to read it as a formula then use this on a VBA Module:

`Public Function evaluateCell(cellValue As String)
    evaluateCell = Evaluate(cellValue)
End Function`

And on Cell A2 do: `=evaluateCell(A1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in google sheets use in cell A2:

```
=QUERY(;"select "&A1)
```

Comment: That is actually pretty interesting. And I can add a Index( , 2) there to return to its on cell instead.